# mariadb, mysql connecting with firebase cloud function

Tags: mysql, firebase, mariadb, google-cloud-functions

I am currently using firebase cloud function.

I want to connect to MariaDB (which one of my client owns). My client doesn't give me API's so I have to send sql queries using firebase cloud functions.

But if when i try to connect and send query, MySQL sends me an error. which is down below.

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/user_code/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:188:13)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

Here is my code.

```
    var mysql      = require('mysql2');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : server,
        user     : user,
        password : password,
        database : databaseName,
        port     : port
    });


    return connection.query(" select * From USER where user_id = '" + userid + "'",
        function (err, rows, fields) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(rows);
            console.log(fields);
            if (err) throw err;

            if(rows["user_id"] == userid && rows["user_pw"] == userpw) {
                if(rows["del_yn"] == "N"){
                    res.status(200).send(rows);
                }
                else{
                    res.status(410).send('deleted');
                }
            }
            else {
                res.status(401).send('login err');
            }
        });
```

any help..??

Comment: Are you on a paid firebase plan? If not you can only connect to Google servers and that could be why you cannot connect?

Comment: @sketchthat oh! you were right! thank you!

Comment: @jbyun94 Could you share billing impact when connecting with external mySQL from cloud functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert your payment for firebase plan. that made me get etimedout error. (firebase only allows to Only Google server if not paid)